# Mysql : get count and percent for all entries of a table with given conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say we have the following model :

- A table of exercises (id, name)
- A table of users (id, name, email)
- A tables of exams (id, user_id, day)
- A join table between exams and exercises (exam_id, exercise_id)
- Each user can make one exam each day.
- Each exam is made of many exercises (has and belongs to many).

For each user (when logged), I would like to display a table displaying all the exercises and for each the count and percent of exams the user made during a given period of time (using the day attribute of the exams).

At this time I can display all the exercises the user made and their percent during a given period with the following query.

```
    SELECT 
       o.user_id,
       o.exercise_id, 
       o.exercise_name, 
       COUNT(*) AS nb_exams,
       (COUNT(*) * 100 / (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM exams
              LEFT JOIN users ON exams.user_id = users.id 
           WHERE users.id = 1 AND exams.day >= "2015-09-01" AND exams.day <= "2015-09-07"
       )) AS percent
    FROM (
        SELECT
            exercises.id AS exercise_id,
            exercises.name AS exercise_name, 
            exams.id AS exam_id, 
            users.id AS user_id
        FROM exercises 
            LEFT JOIN exercises_exams ON exercises_exams.exercise_id = exercises.id
            LEFT JOIN exams ON exercises_exams.exam_id = exams.id 
            LEFT JOIN users ON exams.user_id = users.id 
        WHERE users.id = 1 AND exams.day >= "2015-09-01" AND exams.day <= "2015-09-07"
        GROUP BY exercise_id,exam_id
    ) AS o
    GROUP BY exercise_id;
```

But I also want to display the exercises he did not make yet with a value of 0.

Is it possible to do this with one query of mysql ?

EDIT-

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aabd4d/1) for the current query. You will notice that only the 3 exercises which are used in exams are returned. I would like to list all the exercises with the count and percent (even the fourth with 0)

Comment: could you please set up a sql fiddle for this?

Comment: @vkp I edited my question with the sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should remove the `where` condition to the `join` clause in the inner query to see a `0` result when an exercise wasn't performed. Getting a `user_id` corresponding to the `0` result doesn't make sense. This is the closest solution i can think of.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aabd4d/81)

```
SELECT 
   o.user_id,
   o.exercise_id, 
   o.exercise_name, 
   sum(case when exam_id is null then 0 else 1 end) AS nb_exams,
   (sum(case when exam_id is null then 0 else 1 end) * 100 / (
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM exams
       LEFT JOIN users ON exams.user_id = users.id 
     where exams.day >= "2015-09-01" AND exams.day <= "2015-09-07"
   )) AS percent
FROM (
    SELECT
        exercises.id AS exercise_id,
        exercises.name AS exercise_name, 
        exams.id AS exam_id , 
        users.id AS user_id
    FROM exercises 
        LEFT JOIN exercises_exams ON exercises_exams.exercise_id = exercises.id
        LEFT JOIN exams ON exercises_exams.exam_id = exams.id 
        and exams.day >= "2015-09-01" AND exams.day <= "2015-09-07"
        LEFT JOIN users ON exams.user_id = users.id 
) AS o
GROUP BY exercise_id,exercise_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting the 0 results for a given user makes a sense in my case because I want to show to the user the exercises he did not already make during its exams and have a way to order the results according to the percent.

Comment: try the modified query in the fiddle that has been updated